# UART Transmitter implementation using Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, uart, state-machines

I am trying to implement the UART transmitter FSM using Verilog, but the FSM is stuck at `IDLE` state. Can someone tell what mistakes am I making? The code is as below.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
  module Transmitter(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] data,
    input Tx,
    input reset,
    output reg TxD
    );
    parameter BaudRate=921600;
    parameter clk_rate=100000000;
    
    integer bit_counter=0;
    reg [1:0]state, next_state; 
    
    localparam clk_per_bit=(clk_rate/BaudRate);
    integer clocks_counter=0; 
  
    localparam IDLE=2'd0;
    localparam START=2'd1;
    localparam TRANSMIT=2'd2;
    localparam END=2'd3;

  always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if(reset)
      begin
      bit_counter<=0;
      clocks_counter<=0;
      state<=IDLE;
      end
    else if (clocks_counter< clk_per_bit)
     clocks_counter<=clocks_counter+1;
    else begin state<=next_state; clocks_counter<=0; end
  
  always@(*)
    case(state)
      IDLE:   begin
                 TxD=1;
                 next_state= Tx ? START:IDLE;
               end
      
      START:   begin TxD=0;
                     next_state= TRANSMIT;
               end
      
      TRANSMIT:begin TxD=data[bit_counter];
                     bit_counter=bit_counter+1;
                     next_state= (bit_counter>7)? END:TRANSMIT;
               end
      END:   begin TxD=1;
                  next_state= IDLE;
               end
      
      
    endcase
  
endmodule
```

Here is the code link to view simulation result:

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/giPm

Answer (score 3):

Another problem is that you have the statement

```vhdl
        bit_counter = bit_counter + 1;
```

in an unclocked `always` block -- this will not work. You will need to move that to the clocked block, incrementing the bit_counter at the same time you assign the next state, but only if you're in the TRANSMIT state.

Comment: Exactly,it will cause an inferred latch other wise which will bring racing issue

Answer (score 2):

The `Tx` pulse is too short.  You need to keep it high long enough for `counter` to roll over (from 108 to 0).  In the testbench, change:

```
  #2 Tx=0;
```

to something like:

```
  #1200 Tx=0;
```

`clk_per_bit` is 108.

Now you will see `state` change from `IDLE` TO `START`:

[image: waves]